# Node- Can't attach key/value to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using Node. This is weird, I am not able to attach a key/value....`broadcastStamp = date` to the object result. I verified with typeof it is a object. There is no error...the key/value is just simply not there.

```
function broadcastSingleClient(result, event, httpObject) {
    var date = new Date().valueOf();
    result.broadcastStamp = date; 
    console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE**: This object is coming from a mongoose/mongodb query call back function:

```
Object.keys(models).forEach(function (model) {
    models[model].find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).exec(
        function (err, result){
            broadcastSingleClient(result[0], model+"Result", res);
        });
```

When doing this query in the shell without the exec() call back, I am able to attach to the object.

Comment: So what do you get when you log it ?

Comment: The whole json object without the addition of `broadcastStamp = date`

Comment: If I recall correctly Mongoose objects have property getters and setters which do validation and other work behind the scene. Is the `broadcastStamp` a field of the model schema?  are you setting a valid value?

Comment: No, it is not a field. It is attached to json object(document) before it is broadcasted as a time stamp of the broadcast.

Comment: Are you sure object is not frozen? What is the result of `Object.isFrozen(result)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend to save the `result` after you modify it?
Are you using Mongoose virtual properties in your `broadcastSingleClient` function ?

if not then I think you can use `lean` which will return plain js object - without the Mongoose object wrapping it.

Try this:

```
Object.keys(models).forEach(function (model) {
models[model].find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).lean().exec(      // note the "lean"
    function (err, result){
        broadcastSingleClient(result[0], model+"Result", res);
    });
```

Comment: lean() is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I created jsfiddle and it works -- http://jsfiddle.net/volkhin/YGgzL/, I only added result object as `var result = {a: 1, b: 2};`. The only things that comes to my mind is that result is not simple object. It definitely will not work for null, undefined, numbers and so on.

**Edit**:
Then I believe it's due to getters/setters. And it would be better to avoid modifying such object because modifying it can lead to unknown consequences inside mongoose. If you just need to access some data in this object you can try create shallow copy (for example, using underscorejs _.clone or manually iterating over its keys) which will return simple object. Which you can modify, of course. But I'm not sure if it will contain all the data -- again, it might heavily depend on getters/setters.

Comment: You are correct, the object is normal object as far as typeof..but it is from a callback of a mongoose query with the result passed into a call back. I updated my original post with more info.